# Bad code request for face verification in Azure Face API on Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am learning how to use this API, to start with, i thought of running a simple program and this is what happens:
code:

```
subscription_key = "**"
assert subscription_key

face_api_url = 'https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify'




headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}
params = {
    'faceId1': '03ab5c58-86bb-4eef-a89e-56d4ce76e95b',
    'faceId2': '05113848-2c22-4116-8a30-5cde938eec61'
}


import requests
from pprint import pprint
response  = requests.post(face_api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
faces = response.json()
pprint(faces)
```

Output:

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'Request body is invalid.'}}
```

Comment: You provide no data payload to your request. See the Requests documentation for more details http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests Basically you need to replace params with json or data, depending on your data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to solve it. I figured it out:

```
import json
subscription_key = "**"
assert subscription_key

face_api_url = 'https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify'


headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
params = {
    "faceId1": "d4f201e1-8372-4295-ab91-5a148d5932e8",
    "faceId2": "948fb955-5384-42e2-8623-2e44127163f6"
}

body1=json.dumps(params)
import requests
from pprint import pprint
response  = requests.post(face_api_url, headers=headers, data=body1)
faces = response.json()
pprint(faces)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, you were also missing "" in params.

Answer (score 0):

Only difference I see is

```
params = {
    "faceId1": "03ab5c58-86bb-4eef-a89e-56d4ce76e95b",
    "faceId2": "05113848-2c22-4116-8a30-5cde938eec61"
}
```

**UPDATE**

Few tips that should be followed

1. Make sure the API region is same as your subscription keys
2. Make sure you are using right endpoint, refer overview tab in cognitive service to get right endpoint.

Comment: But that's for face detection I believe. I'm trying the face verification API. I'd be glad for any help.

Comment: Ahh that is my complete miss, have you tried face to person verification request just in case if that works?

Comment: I haven't, I'll try it once and get back to you. But for my application, face to face would be more apt. But any clue as to why this is wrong? I've been following this https://southeastasia.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a

Comment: Hi @ShobhitKumar were you able to try face to person request ?

Comment: hey, thanks for your concern. I was able to make it work the normal  way. I had to pass the faces as body and not params.

Comment: wonderful, please mark up vote if part of solution helped you, "seems the one".